# Write a function that computes and returns the total number of integers between two target numbers that are divisible by 3

Tags: c++, function

I was assigned to write this code and it seemed pretty simple at first. I wrote it out and tried to understand it as best as I could and really thought I got it down. But when I tried to check the code using VisualStudio, errors with the code popped up and the code would not finishing processing.

Here's the assignment:

Write a function named specialNumbers that computes and returns the total number of integers between two target numbers that are divisible by 3. The function takes two parameters:
1. start, an integer
2. end, an integer bigger than start
The function returns the total number of multiples of 3, between start and end, inclusive.
For example, if start=3, end=10, the function would return 3.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int specialNumbers(int start, int end) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
} 

int main() {
    int a, b;
    cout << "Enter two numbers to find total number of integars divisble by 3 between them" << endl;
    cin >> a, b;
    int n = specialNumbers(a, b);
    cout << "Number of integars divisible by 3 between" << a << "and" << b << "are" << n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error is displays is

> Debug Error! The variable b is used and not initialized

Comment: Please show the errors.

Comment: `cin >> a >>  b;`

Comment: It says the variable b is being using but is has not been initialized but i thought I initialized it properly

Comment: @suspectus thank you so much i should've looked over it more

Comment: Before you turn in your work, note that your algorithm is also in error. For instance if the numbers are 4 and 6 it will return 0 when it should return 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax to extract two ints from `cin`, it should be:

```cpp
cin >> a >> b;
```

---

Your code gives an "uninitialized error" because of the semantics of the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator), which takes two arguments and returns the latter.

Put simply, your code is equivalent to:

```
(cin >> a), b;  // ERROR: `b` isn't being initialized.
```

Comment: Nice answer. I would expect the uninitialized message would be a warning, rather an error (except if warnings are treated as errors in the OP's setting).

Answer (score 1):

The other answers addressed proper use of `cin` however there is also an algorithm error. The code returns an incorrect result if the last number is a multiple of 3.

For instance, if you enter the numbers 4 and 6 it will return 0 when 6 is a multiple of 3 when it should return 1.

This can be corrected by changing:

```
for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
```

to

```
for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
```

However, the algorithm is extremely inefficient when the integers are far apart. Examining each integer would be time consuming if they are, for instance, 15 and 2,000,000,000. This is like multiplying two numbers by just adding one of them over and over.

This code first notices that the number of values divisible exactly by 3 will be unchanged if a multiple of 3 is subtracted from both the start and end values.

Second, after doing this the number of values inclusively between start and end will be exactly the value of `end/3` incremented by one if `start==0`

Thus this code will produce the correct answer without looping:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int specialNumbers(int start, int end) {
    int adj = 3 * (start / 3);  // find and remove the multiples of 3 from start and end
    start = start - adj;        // start will now be either 0, 1 or 2
    end = end - adj;
    int count = end / 3;        // count is the number of exact multiples of 3 in the sequence
    if (start == 0)             // unless the adjusted start is zero in which case it must be incremented
        count++;
    return count;
    }

int main() {
    int a, b;
    while (1) {
        cout << "Enter two numbers to find total number of integars divisble by 3 between them" << endl;
        cin >> a >> b;
        int n = specialNumbers(a, b);
        cout << "Number of integars divisible by 3 between" << a << "and" << b << "are" << n << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or just `count = end/3 - (start-1)/3`. Or `count = end/3 - (start+2)/3 + 1`, to cope with the special case `start=0`.

Comment: @TonyK Yep. The special case occurs 1/3 of the time so it's pretty significant. I broke it down to, hopefully, be clear. It actually astonishes me that this question and answers let such an error escape notice so long. SO contributers are usually quite on top of things.

Comment: The special case is not `(start % 3) == 0`, it's just `start == 0`. So it probably doesn't occur a third of the time.

Comment: @TonyK After adjustment, start is either 0, 1 or 2 with an equal distribution assuming the original start and end are randomly distributed. So the probability is 1/3.  However, while I had already noted that the adjusted start was within the range 0,1, and 2, the modulo operator is redundant so the expression `start % 3==0` s/b just `start==0` Thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: _My_ `start` is unadjusted. So it can take any non-negative value, not just 0-2.

Comment: @TonyK Right, we have different "special cases" and "starts"  Nice short one liners.

Comment: @TonyK  I think you should write this up as an answer. Your approach, which determines the number of values divisible by 3 from 0 to the end and subtracting the number of those from 0 to the start-1, is straightforward. I've run across similar problems in my own code doing image resampling so it isn't purely a homework type question and might have value to others. In any case just incrementing and testing over the range is pretty inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

ChangeChange this:

```
cin >> a, b;
```

to:

```
cin >> a >> b;
```

since you definetely don't want the comma operator in this case, but the `>>` operator.